# Woocommerce вывод товаров определенных категорий в магазине

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Нужно в магазине woocommerce запретить показ товаров из определенных категорий.
Ну или показывать товары определенных категорий.
Шорткод на отдельной странице не подходит.

Answer (score 1):

> Запрет вывода категории test.

```
function custom_pre_get_posts_query( $q ) {

    $tax_query = (array) $q->get( 'tax_query' );

    $tax_query[] = array(
           'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
           'field' => 'slug',
           'terms' => array( 'test' ), //Категория
           'operator' => 'NOT IN'
    );

    $q->set( 'tax_query', $tax_query );

}
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'custom_pre_get_posts_query' );
```

Еще можно добавить вот такую вот штуку:

```
function remove_product(){  
    global $post; 

    $args = array( 'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',);
    $terms = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID,'product_cat', $args);

    if ($terms[0]->slug == 'test') { //Категория 
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_output_product_data_tabs', 10 );
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_upsell_display', 15 );
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_output_related_products', 20 );
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_title', 5 );
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 10 );
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_excerpt', 20 );
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_meta', 40 );
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_sharing', 50 );
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_show_product_images', 20 );
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_show_product_sale_flash', 10 );
        add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_thumbnail', '__return_empty_string' );
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail', 10 );
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_show_product_loop_sale_flash', 10 );
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content','woocommerce_breadcrumb', 20, 0);
    }   
} 
add_action( 'wp', 'remove_product', 10 );
```

Вставьте код в function.php